# HotSpot: Session Failed after Login with Phone Embedded Browsers

Tags: login, session, mikrotik, wifi, cookie

Some phones have their embedded browser when they are connecting to HotSpot. (For example in iPhone (iOS) or Windows Phone 8.1).

The problem is after login into these browsers (with embedded browser), the session failed in the phone browser (For example Safari or IE). The visual image shows my problem:

http://oi59.tinypic.com/2lbidef.jpg

How can I manage this? Is the embedded browser and phone browser have the same cookie? If they are not the same, how can I manage the sessions?

Is there any way to call the main browser (after connecting to HotSpot) instead of embedded browser?

And these are my hardwares/softwares for the HotSpot (if needed):

- Mikrotik HotSpot
- My Login System (Mikrotik Redirection Solution)
- FreeRADIUS (Radius Server)

Comment: Is the login on the phone the same as the My Login System page? Maybe it is using the WiSPr XML interface and the phone uses its own form to post the credentials. Maybe this is incompatible with your 'My Login System'.

Comment: I use MikroTik External Login Page: http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/HotSpot_external_login_page

Comment: Can you post your configuration using '/export' in the terminal. Also please attach the log entries of the router and FreeRADIUS when the user was logged in.

Comment: Sorry, I can't do this do to confidentiality of the project. But is there any general solution for the problem?

Comment: I found this solution but I didn't try it yet. http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Customizing_Hotspot#iOS_popup_checker_override. I think this could be an answer.

Comment: "This is useful for setups where you use Cookies. Since the iPhone popup login window doesn't support Cookies, you might want to force users to open Safari for logging in." How about disabling cookie authentication? It is a security feature but in 8 years of work for hotspot providers I only saw active mac spoofing twice.

Comment: What is "active mac spoofing"?

Comment: Mac address spoofing is when a user would change it's network adapters hardware address (mac) and change it to a mac address that is already authenticated. With the word 'active' I meant 'a user actively used' and is not a technical term in this context. I see no big drawbacks when not using cookie authentication.

Comment: Thank you for your information. Sorry that I don't have enough reputations to UpVote your comments.

Comment: No problem, good luck! I do not think this question and my probable answer (referring to documentation, as you did yourself) for this very specific problem is up to par with the quality requirements of this site.